# Is it possible to scale a custom cursor image using CSS

Tags: css, cursor

With high DPI desktop devices becoming increasingly common, I'm finding that my custom cursors don't always look great. But if I use media queries to change to @2x/@3x image files, the cursor doubles or triples in size.

Is scaling the cursor something that is possible, or is it not yet part of the standard?

Of course, I'd prefer a CSS solution, but if it needs to be JS, that is also okay, as long is it isn't something that will degrade accessibility.

Update: I have now tried switching to SVG cursors, but on Macos Chrome and Safari, these are even more blurry than PNG images (though they are perfectly crisp on Firefox).